# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 2535, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I want to make application using opencv for phone camera using and tensorflow lite to detect objects. So I found nice code from github https://github.com/bendahouwael/Vehicle-Detection-App-Android that uses opencv for camera and tensorflow lite. To test my own tensorflow lite files, I changed `objectDetectorClass=new objectDetectorClass(getAssets(),"ssd_mobilenet.tflite","labelmap.txt",300);` to `objectDetectorClass=new objectDetectorClass(getAssets(),"tiny-416.tflite","car.txt",416);` which is located in `CameraActivity.java`.

Also, in `objectDetectorClass.java` I changed

```
if(quant==0){
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*1*416*416*3);
        }
        else {
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*1*416*416*3);
        }
```

I uploaded my tflite file in my github https://github.com/dohnutSeo/my-own-tensorflow-lite-file/tree/main with label txt in readme.

And the whole error message in Android Studio is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.Detection, PID: 19290
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 2535, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:482)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:252)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:175)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:360)
        at com.example.imagepro.objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage(objectDetectorClass.java:92)
        at com.example.imagepro.CameraActivity.onCameraFrame(CameraActivity.java:125)
        at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:392)
        at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:373)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I searched for this issue and found many question that said input tensor size is different with original tflite file. So I tried to change the size in this code but could not find how to change it. Help me to solve this issue.

Also I used this site https://netron.app/ to see the shaped of my own tensorflow lite file which says input is

```
name: input_1
type: float32[1,416,416,3]
location: 0
```

Thanks for all replies!

Edit1)
To answer @Farmaker, do you mean the code from objectDetectorClass.java?

```
float[][][]boxes =new float[1][10][4];
float[][] scores=new float[1][10];
float[][] classes=new float[1][10];
```

I changed it to

```
float[][][]boxes =new float[1][2535][4];
float[][] scores=new float[1][10];
float[][] classes=new float[1][10];
```

but still I had errors.

Comment: From Netron I see input is float32[1,416,416,3] and the outputs are float32[1,1,4] and float32[1,1,3]...so there is nowhere [1,10,4] shape. Have you made appropriate changes to the Java code? Have you changed all the dimensions of the arrays?

Comment: I edited my question to answer yours. Please see the last part of my question, thank you

Comment: It seems that it is something wrong with your file. As I have written above your outputs at netron are 2...and inside your code you have 3 with totally different dimensions. Check netron...and the way you create your tflite file.

Comment: My tflite file worked well in this project. https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite

And I made my tflite file following this colab site : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OKzbccsdA40sJ67gqmNyblWuEMCfP5zx?usp=sharing

Does my tflite file have possibility that it is wrong?

Comment: Yes, the outputs are totally wrong for this project. If it worked for another project check the output differences and adapt the code.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the another project the code about output part again.

Comment: I can't find the output part of this code https://github.com/bendahouwael/Vehicle-Detection-App-Android. Have any ideas?